# Sending data thru the USB port

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, transfer

Any idea how to program data transfer through the USB serial port of an Android phone; piloted from the phone?

Answer (score 3):

There is USB support starting with Android 3.1. Check here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html

Comment: And is back-ported to 2.3.4 as well

Comment: but doesn't work on all devices - eg Samsung Galaxy never got it to work

Answer (score 2):

There is no support in the Android SDK for communicating over USB, sorry.